# 403 error on .exe files apache

Tags: apache, http-status-code-403

I have an apache webserver running on centos environment. There is a folder and in that there is a file which has an extension .exe lets name the file x.exe

when I try download this file using http://mysite.com/folder/x.exe I get a 403 error.

but if I add a gif to that folder it works http://mysite.com/folder/pic.gif

I dont have SSH access to this server but need to know some clue for why this is happenning, the file permissions are correct too.

any help is appreciated

Comment: The error log will probably reveal more details.

Comment: the thing is that I dont have any access to the error log or at least the shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well the answer was I had this in a folder where it forbids the exe

```
Deny from all
<FilesMatch "\.(html|HTML|htm|HTM|xhtml|XHTML|js|JS|css|CSS|bmp|BMP|png|PNG|gif|GIF|jpg|JPG|jpeg|JPEG|ico|ICO|pcx|PCX|tif|TIF|tiff|TIFF|au|AU|mid|MID|midi|MIDI|mpa|MPA|mp3|MP3|ogg|OGG|m4a|M4A|ra|RA|wma|WMA|wav|WAV|cda|CDA|avi|AVI|mpg|MPG|mpeg|MPEG|asf|ASF|wmv|WMV|m4v|M4V|mov|MOV|mkv|MKV|mp4|MP4|swf|SWF|flv|FLV|ram|RAM|rm|RM|doc|DOC|docx|DOCX|txt|TXT|rtf|RTF|xls|XLS|xlsx|XLSX|pages|PAGES|ppt|PPT|pptx|PPTX|pps|PPS|csv|CSV|cab|CAB|arj|ARJ|tar|TAR|zip|ZIP|zipx|ZIPX|sit|SIT|sitx|SITX|gz|GZ|tgz|TGZ|bz2|BZ2|ace|ACE|arc|ARC|pkg|PKG|dmg|DMG|hqx|HQX|jar|JAR|xml|XML|pdf|PDF)$">
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

added exe there and worked fine,

also a note, this was in a SilverStripe CMS powered site, and in the assets folder of SilverStripe

Comment: So my answer was correct... could have just left a comment bro.

Comment: ha! i know, did posted a answer as the .htaccess was a bit long :P yeah your answer is correct, cheers

Comment: This worked perfect for me. I was running silverstripe so that's probably why.

Answer (score 3):

Within Apache's `httpd.conf`, it is possible to specify default handling actions for certain file types or paths. It may be that your server is configured to block executable files all together. Similar blocking can also occur in an `.htaccess` file. There are a few ways to do it... here's one:

```
<Files ~ "\.exe$">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

That little snippet could be in the main `.conf` file, and included `.conf` file, OR an `.htaccess` file (or all three!), and again, that is just **one** possibility. Your best bet is to check out the server logs. They will indicate why a given request was denied in a form similar to this:

> [Wed Oct 11 14:32:52 2000] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by
>   server configuration: /www/root

Take a look at [this document](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html) for information about server logs (including default paths to the logs themselves).

As I mentioned, there are a few other ways to block access to certain file types, certain files, certain folders, etc. Without looking at the error logs, it is very difficult to determine the cause. Further, without full access to the server, it may not be possible to alter this behavior. This blockage could be in place as a matter of policy for your web host.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to add I spent like 2 hours trying this crap over and over again only to discover that selinux was denying specific file types for httpd.

try:

setenforce Permissive

and see if that corrects the error

tag
Fedora 16