# 403 error while trying to download a exe from my web server

Tags: java, apache, http, web

I keep getting a 403 error and I tried everything to get it right for my auto updater for something that I'm making which is supposed to get a .exe and replace the old .exe with the new updated one...

```
package cyara;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.nio.channels.Channels;
import java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel;

public class Controller {
    public Label latest;
    public Label verision;
    private String version = "1.0";

    public void downloadLatest(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        verision.setText("Current Updater Version " + version);
        latest.setText("Downloading Files");

        String url = "https://www.kadepcgames.com/downloads/cyara/b-0001/latest/Cyara.exe";

        try {
            latest.setText("Connecting to www.kadepcgames.com/downloads/cyara/b-0001/latest/Cyara.exe");
            downloadUsingNIO(url, "/Program Files/Cyara/Cyara.exe");
            latest.setText("Trying to download the backup");
            downloadUsingStream(url, "/Program Files/Cyara/CyaraBackup.exe");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            latest.setText("Download Failed!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void downloadUsingStream(String urlStr, String file) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(urlStr);
        URLConnection uc;
        uc = url.openConnection();
        uc.addRequestProperty("User-Agent",
                        "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)");
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        FileOutputStream fis = new FileOutputStream(file);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int count = 0;
        while ((count = bis.read(buffer,0,1024)) != -1) {
            fis.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }
        fis.close();
        bis.close();
    }

    private static void downloadUsingNIO(String urlStr, String file) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(urlStr);
        URLConnection uc;
        uc = url.openConnection();
        uc.addRequestProperty("User-Agent",
                        "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)");
        ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(url.openStream());
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
        fos.close();
        rbc.close();
    }

}
```

And I'm getting the 
`java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://www.example.com/downloads/cyara/b-0001/latest/Cyara.exe` error
Mostly tried tutorials but none of them worked for me. So really the only thing I thought was the permissions (which I checked) and still even after setting them to 777 no luck at all!
I'm really getting tired of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest checking the apache configuration.  It is possible that apache is blocking the request due to the .exe extension.

Take a look at this post:
[403 error on .exe files apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8478279/403-error-on-exe-files-apache)